# Navigation Component Safe Args Pass List Data

Tags: android

I'm using Twitter API. I have a home fragment and detail fragment. I'm getting followers and friends in home fragment because I'm showing non-followers count, unfollowers count etc. so I already have non-followers back list. I want to pass that lists detail page. I'm using Navigation Component. This lists types are: List -> User class not created by me. This is com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User. User class serializable class. I'm not pass this lists because there arent parcelable.

context my navigation.xml:

```
 <argument
            android:name="list"
            app:argType="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User[]" />
```

in home fragment:

```
val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToDetailFragment(list.toTypedArray())
            requireView().findNavController().navigate(action)
```

I'm getting this error in detail fragment args:

```
  @NonNull
  public Bundle toBundle() {
    Bundle __result = new Bundle();
    if (arguments.containsKey("list")) {
      User[] list = (User[]) arguments.get("list");
      __result.putParcelableArray("list", list);
    }
    return __result;
  }
```

__result.putParcelableArray("list", list); line error

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Navigation (2.3.1)? What is the exact error message that you're getting? Is your `User` class Parcelable?

Comment: User class serializable

Comment: So what version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: I'm using latest version. User class serializable. Error says: User[] cannot be converted to Parcalable[]